# How To Access Specified Field Of ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox which gets Text and Value fields from a DataTable object.

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtSip.Rows)
       {
         cbxSipNo.Items.Add(new { Text = dr[0].ToString() ,Value = dr[2].ToString()});
       }
       cbxSipNo.ValueMember = "Value";
       cbxSipNo.DisplayMember = "Text";
```

My problem is while accessing that specified Text and Value fields as below.

```
if (cbxSipNo.Items.Contains( new { Text= row.Cells[5].Value.ToString()} )
   {
    //some code
   }
```

While doing contains, I couldn't figure out to access Text field. When i try without new syntax, it looks for Text and Value field combination. How can i do contains in the Text field of ComboBox?

Comment: You should do `cbxSipNo.DataSource = dtSip`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya my dtsip has many columns, could u explain that more detailed please

Comment: Set the `DisplayMember` to the name of the column which provides the items to display and the `ValueMember` to the name of the column which provides the related values, if the value (`SelectedValue`) should be different from the one displayed.

Comment: @Jimi ok I got what you mean but after that how can I access that Display member field in contains method? Thats the real issue

Comment: The `DisplayMember` is the name of a column, the `SelectedItem` returns a `DataRowView`; you can (for example) cast `SelectedItem` to  `DataRowView` `(cbxSipNo.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row["Display Member Name"].ToString();`. More or less the same for the `SelectedValue`, if needed.

Comment: @Jimi I have no problem about SelectedItem my problem is that I cant make contains work.

Comment: `Contains` is provided by the `Row.ItemArray` element. So you could have something like: `var theRow = cbxSipNo.Items.OfType<DataRowView>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Row.ItemArray.Contains("Some Value")); if (theRow != null) theValueToReturn = theRow["The Value Member"].ToString();` The last `ToString` should probably be a cast to the correct type.

Comment: @CanESER, I added my answer below, view it might be it help you :)

Comment: You should use DataBindings or a DataView, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a class.

```
class MyItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And add your data row value to an object of an above class to combo box like

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtSip.Rows)
{
    cbxSipNo.Items.Add(new MyItem { Text = Convert.ToString(dr[0]), Value = Convert.ToString(dr[2]) });
}
```

And then you can cast your combo box items to above `MyItem` class and then check whether `Any` item present in combo box that contains your data row value

```
string str = row.Cells[5].Value; 

if (cbxSipNo.Items.Cast<MyItem>().Any(x => Convert.ToString(str).Contains(x.Text)))
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear, and Welcome, Vote up if possible :)